# KERNELS path for USB device connected to HUB

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev, raspbian, ttyusb

I'm creating udev rules to map my USB devices (ttyUSB*) to the USB ports where they are connected. The usual way to do so is looking at the output of:

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk
```

Here my output (I removed the `ATTRS` lines not meaningful):

```
looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6/1-1.5.6:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6/1-1.5.6:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6/1-1.5.6:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.5.6:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB-RS485 Cable"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

    looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6':
    KERNELS=="1-1.5.6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB-RS485 Cable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="FTY48GF2"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5':
    KERNELS=="1-1.5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.9.41-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb':
    KERNELS=="3f980000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
    KERNELS=="soc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Here the connection: Raspberry Pi -> USB HUB -> FTDI dongle.
My rule is the following:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules 
KERNEL=="1-1.5.6", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYMLINK+="rs485"
```

but:

```
# ls -l /dev/rs485 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Oct  4 07:04 /dev/rs485 -> bus/usb/001/009
```

I was expecting the symlink should be created to /dev/ttyUSB0.
Now, I understand my dongle is at that usb position from:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. M-UAS144 [LS1 Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
...
```

but of course it IS NOT the serial port (i.e. I cannot `echo` to it).
Trying to use `1-1.5.6:1.0` as KERNEL key doesn't work - no symlink created.

What value should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `man udev`, `KERNELS` searches the device path, while `KERNEL` matches the device itself, and `SUBSYSTEM` represents the part of the kernel generating the event. When your USB dongle is plugged in, *several* udev events are created, as parts of the kernel discover the device and react according.

You want your rule to trigger on the action for the device itself (`SUBSYSTEM=="tty"`, because you want a link for `/dev/ttyUSB0`), but with `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`, it triggers when the USB device itself is discovered, not when the driver for the USB device is started. That's why you get a link to the USB device as seen from the USB subsystem, `bus/usb/001/009o`.

So what you need is

```
KERNELS=="1-1.5.6", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SYMLINK+="rs485"
```

(note the `S` and the `tty`).

Comment: Great explanation. I was wrong reading this https://www.element14.com/community/community/design-challenges/sci-fi-your-pi/blog/2015/07/15/persistent-names-for-usb-devices instead of the manual.